# AWS cloudformation package in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I just want to ask if there is any way that I can make the aws cloudformation package in python? Here is the code in awscli:

```
aws cloudformation package \
        --region us-east-1 \
        --profile $Profile \
        --template-file templates/$TEMPLATE.yml \
        --s3-bucket $ARTIFACT_BUCKET \
        --output-template-file $d-$TEMPLATE-$Profile.packaged.yml
```

I want this to have in python? Thanks! any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `os.system(f"aws cloudformation package --region us-east-1 {Profile} --template-file templates/$TEMPLATE.yml --s3-bucket {ARTIFACT_BUCKET} --output-template-file {d}-{TEMPLATE}-{Profile}.packaged.yml")` Your question is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: This is a special command provided by the AWS CLI. It is not an API call to AWS. Thus, it is not available in boto3 AWS SDK for Python.

Comment: Got it John thank you! Thanks anyway Marcin.

Answer (score 1):

There are two way:

1. Use Python Objective Oriented Programming Library for CloudFormation and let the library to handle your nested stack and packaging. here's an example: https://cottonformation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-cottonformation-by-example/index.html#nested-stack-template
2. Use subprocess standard library to call shell command from Python:

```py
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.run(
    [
        "aws", "cloudformation", "package",
        "--region", "us-east-1"
        "--profile", os.environ["Profile"], # use os.environ to get the env var value
        "--template-file", f'templates/{os.environ["TEMPLATE"]}.yml',
        "--s3-bucket", os.environ["ARTIFACT_BUCKET"],
        "--output-template-file", f'{os.environ["d"]}-{os.environ["TEMPLATE"]}-{os.environ["Profile"]}.packaged.yml',
    ],
    check=True, # if failed, stop the script immediately, prevent the sub sequence command to run
)
```